How can i add a checkbox to AntDesing table in Reactjs and get the data?
I have an Ant table as follows
  <TableAnt dataSource={users} columns={Usercolumns}

I want to be able to put a checkbox on each row and only allow single row selection.
I want to the user to be able to click a row and use that data when they click on a button
do i need to setState of variables ?
How can i do this ?
UPDATE:
this {rowSelection={{ }
{    type: 'checkbox', }
{    onselect: (record) => { }
{        console.log({record}) }
{    } }
{}} }


See the API documentation for how to solve this, using the render property in a column configuration you can put anything into a table column
const columns: ColumnProps<any>[] = [
    {
      title: "Actions",
      dataIndex: "actions",
      key: "actions",
      render: (text, record, index) => <div><button>Click!</button></div>,
    }
]

https://ant.design/components/table#column

i was looking for something like in the question under UPDATE:, Where is the checkbox in this instance and how can i call another function on a different button in the UI and pass the row data ?   Sorry am new to all of this and trying to get the hang of it , thanks

replace the button my example with a Checkbox, create a handler for it and pass the data to the handler, then update a useState variable as you normally would to store the selections. You can use the row selection prop in the same way. If you're actually asking how to implement useState then I'd recommend jumping back to the react tutorials. your updated code snippet with all the brackets everywhere doesnt make much sense I'm afraid. an example of using rowSelection is the third example in the documentation https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-basic copy paste it

why cant i put as in the update above and send the row data ?

the documentation linked shows you exactly the code with working example that you need to complete your task. It wouldn't make sense to duplicate it here as it's subject to change and you should refer to the documentation relevent to the version you are using.

ok ive put the checkbox via the example , but when i click one all get selected , cant see what the issue is . would you be able to help via the example ?

ok i got the selection working  and getting the data , but its just that all the rows get selected when i select just 1 row ?

the example looks like it works, update your question with what you've done.
